# Simulate Spring Controller method model binding in unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring Boot (Spring MVC) I am trying to test the binding of a form to a controller as per #4 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171876/best-way-to-test-thymeleaf-form-spring-mvc-controller-interaction) question.  I am having trouble replicating the magical post request -> model object binding that spring does to pass the model into the controller method.  This is what I have so far:

```
WebRequest postRequest = new ServletWebRequest(new MockHttpServletRequest());
postRequest.setAttribute("itemModel.id", "23", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel();
WebRequestDataBinder dataBinder = new WebRequestDataBinder(itemModel);
dataBinder.bind(postRequest);
assertThat(itemModel.getId(), equalTo(new Long(23)));
```

However, my assertion fails and itemModel.getId() returns null.  How do I initialize the model like spring does when it calls the methods on my @Controller classes?

**UPDATE**

I've updated to the following, but it's still not working:

```
MockHttpServletRequest postRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
postRequest.addParameter("itemModel.id", "23");
WebRequest webPostRequest = new ServletWebRequest(postRequest);
ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel();
WebRequestDataBinder dataBinder = new WebRequestDataBinder(itemModel);
dataBinder.bind(webPostRequest);
assertThat(itemModel.getId(), equalTo(new Long(23)));
```

Comment: Why? Why do you want to test databinding? Don't you trust the ~ 12000 tests that are fired for the spring framework when building? You should be setting the parameter not the attributes. and you should be setting those on the MockHttpServletRequest instead of the wrapping request.

Comment: Here is [the context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171876/best-way-to-test-thymeleaf-form-spring-mvc-controller-interaction).  Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: It also seems that `itemModel.id` should be reduces to `id` as the parameter name.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.  If someone adds an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be just "id", not "itemModel.id"

Answer (score 0):

What about use an Integration test using HttpClient?. Look this example if it's useful for you:

```
      @Test
     public void test() {
             HttpClient loggedClient = new HttpClient();
             PostMethod loginPostMethod = new PostMethod(loginURL);
             loginPostMethod.addParameter("j_username", login);
             loginPostMethod.addParameter("j_password", password);
             loginPostMethod.addParameter("remember", "1");
             loginPostMethod.addParameter("clientType", clientType);
             loginPostMethod.addParameter("clientVersion", clientVersion);
              httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);


             String USERS_URL = HTTP_SERVER_DOMAIN + "/service";
             PutMethod put = new PutMethod(USERS_URL);
             put.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
             put.setRequestBody("your_body");

             try {
                 loggedClient.executeMethod(put);
             } catch (HttpException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             assertEquals(HttpStatus.SC_OK, put.getStatusCode());
```

}

Comment: I'd like to avoid actually running the server and hitting it with HTTP if I can.